# Replace String and ignore case Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have problem with replace some string with upper or lower case

Its my test script:

```
translate=[{'NO': 'frontsplitter', 'DK': 'frontlæbe'}, {'NO': 'diffuser', 'DK': 'diffusor'}, {'NO': 'gitter', 'DK': 'grill'}, {'NO': 'lettmetallfelger', 'DK': 'letmetalfælge'}, {'NO': 'stålfelger', 'DK': 'stålfælge'}, {'NO': 'atv felger', 'DK': 'atv fælge'}, {'NO': 'dekk', 'DK': 'dæk'}, {'NO': 'motorcykeldæk', 'DK': 'Motorcykeldæk & scooterdæk'}, {'NO': 'Go-cart-dæk', 'DK': 'gokartdæk'}, {'NO': 'ophæng', 'DK': 'hjulophæng'}, {'NO': 'parhardstag', 'DK': 'parhardstang'}, {'NO': 'stabstag', 'DK': 'stabilisator'}, {'NO': 'styredempere', 'DK': 'styrdæmpere'}, {'NO': 'Støddæmper\xa0 ', 'DK': 'Støddæmpere'}, {'NO': 'tillinger', 'DK': 'bøsning'}, {'NO': 'ogre varer', 'DK': 'andre varer'}, {'NO': 'Off-road udstyr', 'DK': '4x4 tilbehør'}, {'NO': 'drivlinje', 'DK': 'transmissionsystem'}, {'NO': 'ophæng', 'DK': 'hjulophæng'}, {'NO': 'skærmtiløger', 'DK': 'Skærm-kit'}, {'NO': 'vinsjer', 'DK': 'spil'}, {'NO': 'vinsjutstyr', 'DK': 'spiludstyr'}, {'NO': 'bærbar vinsjer', 'DK': 'bærbare spil'}, {'NO': 'vinsjplater', 'DK': 'spilmonteringsplade'}, {'NO': 'afstogsstykker', 'DK': 'Afstandsstykker\n'}, {'NO': 'kofangere', 'DK': 'kofanger'}, {'NO': 'oget tilbehør', 'DK': 'Andre tilbehør'}]


def translating(string):
    print(translate)
    print(string)

    for row in translate:
        NO=row["NO"]
        DK = row["DK"]


        string=string.replace(NO,DK)
    print(string)
    return string


translating("Dekk Maxxis M8080 Mudzilla 33x13.5-15 110L")
```

how i can ignore case and replace word in this exaple shoud replace Dekk to dæk
or when Dekk replace to Dæk and when dekk then replace to dæk

I need duplicate this on array?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Dæk Maxxis M8080 Mudzilla 33x13.5-15 110L

or When string "dekk Maxxis M8080 Mudzilla 33x13.5-15 110L" then 
dæk Maxxis M8080 Mudzilla 33x13.5-15 110L

ofc its exaple some words can be between some other words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check to see if the first letter is a capital letter, if it is convert it to lower case, replace and then capitalize it again. In the case the word isn't capitalized you can just replace.

```
def translating(string):
        print(translate)
        print(string)

        for row in translate:
            NO=row["NO"]
            DK = row["DK"]

            if string[0].isupper() :
               string=string.lower().replace(NO,DK).capitalize()
            else:
               string=string.replace(NO,DK)

        print(string)
        return string


    translating("Dekk Maxxis M8080 Mudzilla 33x13.5-15 110L")
```

## UPDATE

```
def translating(string):
    print(translate)
    print(string)

    for row in translate:
        NO=row["NO"]
        DK = row["DK"]

        if string.find(NO.capitalize()):
            string=string.replace(NO,DK.capitalize())

        string=string.replace(NO,DK)

    print(string)
    return string
```

Comment: but it will not works when exaple:
translating("maxxis Dekk M8080 Mudzilla 33x13.5-15 110L")

Comment: sorry about that i didn't try out my solution i think the updated version should work :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you don't pay intrest in maintaining the same case for your output string.

You can simply use the

```
string.casefold()
```

option in python to remove all case distinctions present in a python string.

So this is how your function will look

```
def translating(string):
string = string.casefold()


for row in translate:
    NO=row["NO"]
    DK = row["DK"]


    string=string.replace(NO,DK)
print(string)
```

You can also use `string.upper()` to convert the whole string to uppercase or `string.lower()` to convert the whole string to lowercase and then use `string.replace()`.But in these methods the values stored in the "NO" keys have to match with the respective case.

Comment: This is perfect case handling. Upvoting this try two cases it working. @small-atom try this.

Answer (score 1):

The string type doesn't support this. You're probably best off using the regular expression submethod with the re.IGNORECASE option.
Package for that is "re".

Comment: Use comment section to recommend. Answer block add your solution.